# How to clear the console from the 404 error, which you did by fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I needed to to check some URL by fetch if it exist, and rest is some error in console

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    for(let item of data){
      fetch(`variable data by item`)
      .then((res) => res.status)
      .then(res =>{ if(res ===200){
        item.hasUrl = true;
        item.urlImage = `var data`
      }else{
        item.hasUrl = false;
      } })
    }
  },[data])
```

So I need a method to clear the console.

I try to clear it by:

```
console.clear()
```

and if it works, I don't want the message:

> "Console data has been erased"

Anyone have another method to do that?

Comment: Catch the error and do nothing

Comment: I think the browser's own logging of network activity (like 404 errors) isn't something we can control directly from JavaScript code due to security and transparency reasons.

Comment: why are you trying to hide an unsuccessful fetch? Are you doing something malicious? If not, then stop worrying about the console

Comment: If you truly want to hide the request result, make the request in such a way that it always "succeeds" - i.e. through your own server for example, always returning a 200 status, but the data returned determines your codes next actions

Comment: Also, on a JS note: don't use the same name for different things. `fetch(url).then(res => res.status).then(status => ...)`, not `fetch(url).then(res => res.status).then(res => ...)`. That's just asking for future bugs (or headaches at the very least). Also, your `for` is synchronous but `fetch` is async, so that's something else you'll want to fix. Either use a `Promise.all` or use an awaiting foreach (and really: use a `Promise.all`)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a method that clears the JavaScript console and control the browsers output message, *you can't*. Developers don't have access to the browser internal messages.